# auto && outside range-for

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference, auto

Am I right in assuming that writing

```
auto && x = ...;
```

almost never makes sense outside the `for (...)` part of a range for, since if the right-hand side indeed is an rvalue, it will normally stop to exist at the semicolon and then `x` refers to something that has been destroyed.

In other words:

```
Widget f () { ... }
...
auto && x = f();
// do something with x
```

is wrong?

Comment: It's correct. Reference binding extends the lifetime of the temporary.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, I cannot accept comments :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the standard [class.temporary]:

> There are two contexts in which temporaries are destroyed at a different point than the end of the full-expression. The first context is when a default constructor is called to initialize an element of an array.
>
> The second context is when a reference is bound to a temporary. The temporary to which the reference is
>   bound or the temporary that is the complete object of a subobject to which the reference is bound persists
>   for the lifetime of the reference except:
>   — A temporary object bound to a reference parameter in a function call (5.2.2) persists until the completion
>   of the full-expression containing the call.
>   — The lifetime of a temporary bound to the returned value in a function return statement (6.6.3) is not
>   extended; the temporary is destroyed at the end of the full-expression in the return statement.
>   — A temporary bound to a reference in a *new-initializer* (5.3.4) persists until the completion of the
>   full-expression containing the new-initializer.

The line `auto&& x = f();` falls into that second context, and none of the exceptions apply. Thus, the temporary persists for the lifetime of the reference. So there's nothing wrong with that code.